# How can I change the List's row background color in SwiftUI WatchOS App

Tags: swift, swiftui

[See preview screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhNwv.png)

I do not want my `Image` or `Text` to have a grey background like my buttons do. I am using a `List` so that the user can scroll down between the buttons.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Image("Forest1")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .padding(.all)
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
      Text("Welcome Back!")
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Shake Tree")
      }
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Open Forge")
      }
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Open Cabin")
      }
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Open Map")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.listRowBackground(Color.black)` to change the default list row background color to any color.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Image("Forest1")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .padding(.all)
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
        .listRowBackground(Color.black) // <- Here
      Text("Welcome Back!")
        .padding()
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
        .listRowBackground(Color.black) // <- Here
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Shake Tree")
      }
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Open Forge")
      }
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Open Cabin")
      }
      Button(action: PLACEHOLDER) {
        Text("Open Map")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

[image: Preview Screenshot]